# Swift : Using Google Places with iOS and getting -180 as Latitude

Tags: ios, swift

This is my code :

```
func viewController(_ viewController: GMSAutocompleteViewController, didAutocompleteWith place: GMSPlace) {
    print(place.name)
    print(place.placeID)
    print(place.coordinate)
    dismiss(animated: true, completion: nil)
}
```

This is the printing :

```
Name
PlaceID
CLLocationCoordinate2D(latitude: -180.0, longitude: -180.0)
```

Name and PlaceID are correct, but latitude and longitude are incorrect, so how to resolve this?

I found the same problem here [GMSPlace returns invalid coordinate (-180, -180), but name and place ID are correct](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/55978576/gmsplace-returns-invalid-coordinate-180-180-but-name-and-place-id-are-corr)

But I don't understand how to use preyes' answer

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I found it.

Where you present `GMSAutocompleteViewController`, you can add `GMSPlaceField` field to specify what data you want, like this:

```
@objc func autocompleteClicked(_ sender: UIButton) {
  let autocompleteController = GMSAutocompleteViewController()
  autocompleteController.delegate = self

  // Specify the place data types to return.
  let fields: GMSPlaceField = GMSPlaceField(rawValue:UInt(GMSPlaceField.name.rawValue) |
        UInt(GMSPlaceField.placeID.rawValue) |
        UInt(GMSPlaceField.coordinate.rawValue) |
        GMSPlaceField.addressComponents.rawValue |
        GMSPlaceField.formattedAddress.rawValue)!
   autocompleteController.placeFields = fields

  // Specify a filter.
  let filter = GMSAutocompleteFilter()
    filter.type = .noFilter
  autocompleteController.autocompleteFilter = filter

  // Display the autocomplete view controller.
  present(autocompleteController, animated: true, completion: nil)
}
```

I got this function from https://developers.google.com/places/ios-sdk/autocomplete